# USB hub is switched into USB1 mode with USB2 peripherals

Tags: usb, sd-card, usb-hub, pi-a

I was wondering why my USB sd-cardreader operates that slow, see this benchmark:

```
root@DietPi:~# hdparm -tT /dev/sda1

/dev/sda1:
 Timing cached reads:     4 MB in  2.00 seconds =   2.00 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads:   4 MB in  3.96 seconds =   1.01 MB/sec
```

So I checked the USB stats:

```
root@DietPi:~# lsusb -t
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=dwc_otg/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rt2800usb, 12M
```

As shown above, Port1 is in USB 1 mode (not 480M but 12M). Why? How can I change this?

Here the hub and it connected devices, everything is USB 2:

```
root@DietPi:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 14cd:1212 Super Top microSD card reader (SY-T18)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0606 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 2.0 Hub / D-Link DUB-H4 USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How can I change this to full speed?

---

- rbpi model A
- DietPi OS

Comment: a comment [here](https://www.techspot.com/community/topics/could-a-usb-1-1-hub-report-as-usb-2-0-too-slow-to-be-2-0.212307/) states that *"the true Genesys 05e3:0606 is a USB2 hub chip, but there are counterfeit 05e3:0606 that are not"* - I think you have a counterfeit HUB - i.e. the issue is with the **HUB** not the card reader

Comment: @Jarpmanda X: That's interesting info, thanks. Well, this hub have an epoxy blob onboard, it could be possible this is nasty stuff, is a cheap OTG USB adapter. However, is it possible to use (force) another more generic driver instead to see if the situation change? Maybe the detection method is not correct or confused/fooled and doesn't work correctly because of this. Is it possible to use another driver?

Comment: If the device (i.e. the HUB) itself doesn't support USB2.0, then no amount of tweaks, hacks or blind hope that the raspberry pi is at fault will change that

Comment: @JaromandaX, today I installed (it was soldered) another compact hub and there are no problems, 480M now. If you post your comment as answer, I will accept your comment as answer.